# Change UIView width inside CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I got UIView "`statusbar`" as background inside my cell, which works like a progress-bar. The orange view is the statusbar:

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

**THE PROBLEM**

When I launch the app, the statusbar's are ascending for demo usage. BUT **I just cannot change the width of the statusbar** afterwards (after set in the `layoutSubviews()`).

Here is my code for the cell class:

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statusbar: UIView!
    var newWidth = 0
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        statusbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: Int(self.frame.height))
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}

extension MyCollectionViewCell{
    func setStatusbar(completedTasks: Int, totalTasks: Int){
        newWidth = Int((Double(self.frame.width) * (Double(completedTasks) / Double(totalTasks)))) //calculates new width with given tasks
        
        //Local var attempt: (not working)
        /**var frameRect = statusbar.frame;
        frameRect.size.width = newWidth;
        statusbar.frame = frameRect; **/
        
        //Change CGRect attempt: (not working)
        statusbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: Int(self.frame.height))
        
        //Somehow update the cells... should call layoutSubviews here?
        reloadInputViews()
    }
}
```

And in my ViewController.swift I change the statusbars width by `cell.setStatusbar(completedTasks: indexPath.row, totalTasks: 47)`

Here are the both important funcs from ViewController.swift, from where I want to change the statusbar:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xF444444)
    cell.setStatusbar(completedTasks: indexPath.row, totalTasks: 47) //Makes the statusbar increasing with every cell for testing when launched
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.setStatusbar(completedTasks: 47, totalTasks: 47) //Should make the statusbar to 100% (equal width as cell) for testing!
    collectionview.reloadData()
}
```

Can someone help me... I just cannot change the with of "statusbar" (the orange UIView) :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `collectionview.reloadData()` in `didSelectItemAt` as that's causing all of your cells to reload themself and set `completedTasks` back to `indexPath.row`

You shouldn't need to reload the collectionview once you've called `setStatusBar`, or call `layoutSubviews` (you shouldn't call that directly anyway, you should use `setNeedsLayout`)